# Wxwidgets: Which function is better to show changing data on the screen?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm thinking of which function is the fastest to display refreshing data on the screen. I've tested `StaticText->SetLabel(data)` and (`TextCtrl->AppendText(data)`) and `(*TextCtrl2) <<data`. 
`StaticText->SetLabel(data)` was the fastest method from above. Do you know any other methods? 
I need fast method that uses small amount of memory. I've read documentation but I don't know If I've missed something. Any answer will be useful, also the answer "there is no better method".

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: That won't refresh the screen immediately: you need to call StaticText->Update() before anything will change.  If you don't want flickering, call StaticText->Refresh(): that waits until the next paint event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No standard control such as `wxStaticText` nor `wxTextCtrl` will be optimal if your main concern is the speed of updating after appending text to it, they are both generic purpose and have to worry about being efficient in other, completely different, scenarios as well. So if you absolutely need the fastest possible solution, you will need to implement a custom control.

To be honest though, I have trouble seeing a realistic situation in which using `wxStaticText::SetLabelText()` (not `SetLabel()`, unless you really want it to mangle any ampersands in your text) wouldn't be enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll think about it.